# How to select and apply styles for html element which has no defined child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to select and apply styles for html element which has no defined child element? For example:

```
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Isum <span>dolor</span></p>
```

I want to apply some styles for the first p because it doesn't contain span element.

Is it possible to do by CSS?

Comment: You can only travel down the DOM so you can't select the parent - you can't do it with css. You will need javascript.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in CSS.

Comment: Nope, not possible. And by "defined child" you probably mean "child element".

Comment: Note that this has been [proposed in the CSS selectors level 4 spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to put a selector on that first p to do this in CSS only:

http://jsfiddle.net/6EmxP/

You can use the jQuery route to do the same thing.

Comment: It's possible to have many p and I do not know which one has a child.

Comment: If you don't know which p will have the span child then you will have to go with a javascript/jQuery solution. Currently there is no way to move up the DOM with CSS, you can use jQuery to get around that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give that `<p>` a class or something like that?
If you want it to be dynamic add a class to using javascript. You can setup conditions better with that. CSS is not your answer in this case. This can be helpful in some ways :) http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with css. You can do it with jQuery...

See http://api.jquery.com/has/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select the parent, I think..

```
<p class="Lorem">Lorem</p>
<p>Isum <span>dolor</span></p>


.Lorem + p {color: green;}
```

Comment: If you're still curious about the parent selector. Read this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 0):

Your first `p` element actually has a child: It's a text node. Otherwise, `:empty` could be used.

When you know the exact position of the element, `:nth-child` can be used. There is no need for a class (but it would be faster).

Comment: By "child" I meant any child html element. Sorry.